# How to use the derived models by WEKA to apply for new input data

Tags: weka

I am using WEKA 3.8.6 to generate models for prediction purposes. I have the model but I do not know how to use my own parameters to see the results by utilizing the model. What may I do?

I am trying to develop and compare the set of models for predicting contamination levels in vegetable tissues. I developed a set of models (IBK, Additive regression, and random tree) by WEKA 3.8.6 and now I can not use my own data for the prediction for my experiment. How can I evaluate the models and reach outputs?

Comment: Did you have a look at the FAQ [How do i make predictions with a trained model](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/faqs/how_do_i_make_predictions_with_a_trained_model/) on the Weka wiki?

Comment: Thank you, I used the keyword and done, also the following youtube video is useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwk8kU0wImk

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.